# The meaning of "as it is written in the book"

Tags: meaning

> Candied apple, quince and plum and gourd,
> With jellies smoother than the creamy curd,
> And lucent syrops tinct with cinnamon;
> Manna and dates in argosy transferred
> From Fez; and spiced dainties, every one
> From silken Samarcand to cedared Lebanon.
>
> He repeated it once more, using ‘blander’ for ‘smoother’ in the second line; then wrote it down without erasure, but this time (my set eyes missed no stroke of any word) he substituted ‘soother’ for his atrocious second thought, **so that it came away under his hand as it is written in the book**—as it is written in the book.

This is from ["Wireless"](https://www.kiplingsociety.co.uk/tale/wireless.htm) by Rudyard Kipling.

I don't understand the meaning of **so that it came away under his hand as it is written in the book**

I am glad if someone would kindly teach me.

Answer (score 1):

The character is quoting "The Eve of St Agnes" by John Keats, as the story mentions earlier. This is **the book**. The problem is that when he reads it aloud, he misspeaks. Keats's original text uses the word **soother**, not **smoother.**

The irony is that when the character writes down the words that he falsely remembers, he misremembers what he has spoken the first time. The result is that he writes down the correct words without noticing.

Note that Googling the first line of the poem returns matches Keats's original poem. You could have discovered the error yourself. A big point of the story is that the character has been misquoting Keats repeatedly.

Comment: Jeffrey, thank you very much for your precise answer! It is so helpful!